# asp.net repeater FindControl not work?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater with item template:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater4" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center;width:15%;vertical-align:top">
                        <strong id="author" runat="server" style="color:brown;font-size:20px"><%# Eval("Username") %></strong>
                        <img src="<%# Eval("Avatar") %>" alt="Avatar" />
                        <p>Create At: <%# Eval("createAt") %></p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="margin-left:5%;width:70%;vertical-align:top">
                        <div id="contentTopic" runat="server">
                        <p><%# Eval("TopicContent") %></p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:5%;vertical-align:bottom;margin-left:5%">
                        <asp:Button id="btnSua" runat="server" Text="Update" CssClass="button" Height="30px" Visible="false"/>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Button id="btnXoa" runat="server" Text="Delete" CssClass="button" Height="30px" Visible="false"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

And I want to make those buttons visible when Session["account"]'s value equals the value of <%# Eval("Username")%> but it seem doesn't work, buttons still not visible.

My code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["account"] != null)
        {
            Userzone.Text = Session["account"].ToString();
            Info.Visible = true;
            Logout.Visible = true;
            foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater4.Items)
            {
                HtmlGenericControl author = (HtmlGenericControl)item.FindControl("author");
                string Username = author.InnerText;
                Button btnsua = item.FindControl("btnSua") as Button;
                Button btnxoa = item.FindControl("btnXoa") as Button;

                string account = Session["account"].ToString();
                if (Username == account)
                {
                    btnsua.Visible = true;
                    btnxoa.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    btnsua.Visible = false;
                    btnxoa.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Userzone.Text = "Login";
            Info.Visible = false;
            Info.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Any solution to handle this?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Are you getting the value in author variable ?

Comment: It's run normally, the value in author variable showed too.But instead of show the buttons in item that author variable  = Session["account"], it doesn't.

Comment: If this code not work and buttons not found, then you will get a null exception (looking at that code) - so somewhere else is your problem !

Comment: did the repeater have any items on `Repeater4.Items` at PageLoad ? - debug your code step by step !

Comment: @Aristos yes it did, just the buttons don't  work, but it has no null exception so I think it still found the control author.

Comment: Debug your code, I dont think that the PageLoad is the correct place to make that loop

Comment: @Aristos agree with you, PageLoad does not run the loop. I try to ItemDataBound
It's work but I have null exception on string Username = user.InnerText.ToString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @Aristos, It's will run without checking the Repeater in PageLoad so I use ItemDataBound:

```
protected void Repeater4_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl user =(HtmlGenericControl) e.Item.FindControl("author");
            string Username = user.InnerText.ToString();
            Button btnsua = e.Item.FindControl("btnSua") as Button;
            Button btnxoa = e.Item.FindControl("btnXoa") as Button;
            if (Session["account"] != null)
            {
                string account = Session["account"].ToString();
                if (Username == account)
                {
                    btnsua.Visible = true;
                    btnxoa.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    btnsua.Visible = false;
                    btnxoa.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```